# MQTT.fx tool support for load testing

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, mqtt, google-cloud-iot

Does MQTT.fx tool supports load testing? I want to test GCP cloud IoT core by sending multiple messages.

Comment: For me, I'd probably write an MQTT client app to perform load injection.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use emqtt-bench https://github.com/emqx/emqtt-bench

A high-performance test script

```sh
## 200 clients publish a message every 50ms
## 200 * (1000 / 50) = 4000/s

./emqtt_bench pub -c 200 -t t/1 -h broker.emqx.io -I 50
```

[image]